# Treat soft-deleted record as deleted except when querying by ID

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How to NOT apply @Where clause when querying the record by id so that I can retrieve the soft-deleted record?

When a certain user is deleted, it will store a timestamp in it's deleted field. We want soft-deleted user to be treated as typically deleted record except when it is queried in an endpoint by its ID. (GET /users/:Id).

The current code already already solve one of the requirement which should not return a deleted record when we query all the users. But this doesn't return the soft-deleted record when queried by GET /users/:Id

**Entity**

```
@Entity(name = "user")
@Where(clause = "deleted IS NULL")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<PaginatedResponse<User>> getAllUsers(
        Specification<User> spec,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String[] sort,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "50") int limit,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int offset) {

    List<User> allUsers = userService.findAll(spec);
    List<User> users = userService.findAll(spec, Pageables.with(offset, limit, sort));

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new PaginatedResponse<>(allUsers.size(), limit, offset, users));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId) {
    User user = userService.findOne(userId);
    Objects.requireNonNull(user, "No user with id: " + userId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User> {
}


@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to read about Filters in hibernate. There you can have condition where you want to either return User will deleted id's or not.
Let me share the code.

```
    @Before("@annotation(com.talentica.talentpool.core.applicant.aop.Applicant)")
public void enableUserFilter() {
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
if (session.isConnected() && yourCondition) {
    session.enableFilter("userFilter");
}
```

And apply this on your User entity

```
@FilterDef(name = "userFilter")
@Filters({ @Filter(name = "userFilter", condition = "is_deleted = null") })
public class User implements Serializable {
}
```

You can use it in this way and it must help you.